# Match a pattern not inside of inside of BEGIN and END markers

Tags: regex, perl

I'm implementing a script that will check a file (or files) for a given regex pattern and alert the user if the file contains any matches. However, I'd like to be able to allow users to specify exceptions inside the file (i.e. portions of the file that will not be checked). The way I was thinking of implementing this was with BEGIN:EXCEPTION and END:EXCEPTION markers within the file. The way the script works now is as follows:

(assuming file contents in $_)

```
my $re_dirty = /hello world/; # Simple example
if($re_dirty) {
    # alert that the pattern was found in the file
}
```

I've tried changing this to the following:

```
my $re_dirty = /hello world/; # Simple example
my $begin_token = 'BEGIN:EXCEPTION';
my $end_token = 'END:EXCEPTION';
if($re_dirty && $_ !~ /${begin_token}.*${re_dirty}.*${end_token}) {
    # alert that the patter was found and was not in an exception block
}
```

However, this has obvious problems:
1. It will match if if there is a exception before and after the pattern but the pattern itself is not inside an exception.
2. It will not match if the pattern is in the file twice, but only of them is in an exception block.
3. Possibly more problems??

**A couple of clarifying notes:**
1. Exceptions could span multiple lines.
2. There can be more than one exception block per file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
(my $portion = $_) =~ s/${begin}.*?${end}//gs; # reject anything inside begin/end blocks

if ($portion =~ $re_dirty) {
    # do stuff
}
```

This way you get in $portion only the relevant parts of your file (those *outside* the BEGIN/END tokens). Then you can perform a standard regexp match on the relevant part...
Note the use of '?' modifier, to avoid matching from the first begin token to the last end token...

Comment: I could be wrong on this, but won't this have a problem if there are multiple begin and end exception tags in the file? Or is the substitution regex "greedy" in the sense that it will match the first end tag it sees?

Comment: @Kyle If you use `.*?` it means that it is non-greedy, matching as little as possible. The opposite, one might say.

Comment: @Kyle: TLP did answer perfectly: I used .*? - a non-greedy pattern - just to match the multiple begin/end tags in the file...

Comment: Looks like the problem was that the single line modifier was needed. I updated the answer to include this.

Comment: @Kyle: Thanks! I see your update was rejected, don't Know why... I'll do it right now...

Comment: Eh, think I've been doing too much Javascript lately. Used the wrong comment token.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [flip-flop (range operator)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) in scalar context:

```
if (/$begin/ .. /$end/) {
    if (/$re_dirty/) {
        # do stuff
    }
}
```

This particular usage of the range operator will return false (as a statement) until the left hand side returns true, after which it will return true until the right hand side returns true.

Of course, with this approach, you should read the file in line-by-line mode. But that is a better approach overall, with regard to memory usage.

**Edit:**

If you wanted to match against multiline matches **outside** of such blocks, you would first have to gather the relevant lines as multiline strings:

```
my @outside;
my $content;
while (<$file>) {
    if ( /$begin/ .. /$end/ ) {        # if inside tags
        if (defined $content) {        # if not empty
            push @outside, $content;   # store the scalar into array
            undef $content;            # reset variable
        }
    } else {
        $content .= $_;                # store into scalar
    }
}
push @outside, $content if defined $content;

for my $portion (@outside) {
    if ($portion =~ /$re_dirty/) {     # check for multiline matches
        # do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Would this support exceptions that span multiple lines?

Comment: +1, I remember you mentioning the flip-flop operator in a discussion we had elsewhere about `awk` and now I wanted to post this solution but you beat me to it :-)

Comment: @Kyle This is suited for line-by-line reading of a file, not multiline matching.

Comment: @Kyle Yes, provided that you read the file line-by-line. The quintessential part from the docs: *"[...] It is false as long as its left operand is false. Once the left operand is true, the range operator stays true until the right operand is true, AFTER which the range operator becomes false again*". What does not work OOTB is to match your pattern on the same line but outside of your exception tokens (e.g. `hello world BEGIN:EXCEPTION`).

Comment: @Kyle If you want to match the content inside the begin and end blocks against multiline matches, you could simply put it into a scalar variable, such as with `$content .= $_`.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth Its always nice to pass along knowledge. Information wants to be free. :)

Comment: @Kyle Oh, I see... you are trying to negate the match. So you want to see if `$re_dirty` matches the sections that are not inside the begin and end tags. I'll see if I can fix that for you...

Comment: @Kyle There you go. That'll be 100 Euro.

Comment: Even if you read the file line by line the flip flop can produce undesired results if other content than the token is allowed on the same line as the token. In that case you'd need to iterate by "token", not by line.

Comment: @TLP Haha, I think it's worth it :) I appreciate all your help. I was handed a 1000 line PERL file and asked to add this exception feature so it will take me a while to try to fit your solution into the way the other guy architected the original file, but I think this has definitely put me on the right track.

Comment: @Kyle Sounds like you have your work cut out for you. Good luck. :)

Comment: I like learning, too: I did never use range operator in scalar context, thanks for sharing... But, I wonder why noboy liked MarcoS answer... :-) It looks more compact and simple, to me...

Comment: @MarcoS I like your answer, but it didn't work for me the first time I tried it. Will give it another shot today though.

Answer (score 0):

you could add a boolean to your logic:

```
my $begin_token = 'BEGIN:EXCEPTION';
my $end_token = 'END:EXCEPTION';
my $bool = 0;
$bool = 1 if $begin_token;
$bool = 0 if $end_token
```

then you could test  if $bool is 1 or 0 to skip or not parts of the  code